# Почему не работает is_page Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Требуется сделать так чтобы человек который пришел на сайт мог просмотреть только первый ролик из всех, на данный момент они делятся на Episode 1, Episode 2 и т.д

Код фрейма который отображает видео при залогиненым юзеров

```
<div class="video">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo carbon_get_post_meta($current_episode->ID, 'crb_vimeo_video_id'); ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

Делаю для примера так, но страница перестает отображаться

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        }
    else {
        echo "<span class='label-free'>free</span>";
        }
    else (is_page( 'Episode 1' ) ) {
      echo '<div class="video"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/img_for_online_en.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></div>';
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: У вас два else в одном if - это ошибка синтаксиса. Пользуйтесь современными IDE типа phpStorm, NetBeans, Sublime, они сразу подсвечивают такие конструкции. Из кода непонятно, что вы вообще хотите сделать, поэтому поправить его я не могу.

Comment: @KAGGDesign    Хочу чтобы юзер который не залогинен на сайте мог просматривать все эпизоды с название Episode 1, их штук 20 +-  в общем, сейчас так, если не зарегился на сайте то ничего смотреть не можешь, зарегился смотришь все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код должен быть примерно таким, с вложенными if

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( is_page( 'Episode 1' ) ) {
        echo '
        <div class="video">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/img_for_online_en.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
        </div>';
    } else {
        echo "<span class='label-free'>free</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: то, но не то) это будет работать на пользователя зарегистрированного на сайте, а мне наоборот надо, и вот тут у меня проблема(

Comment: Вы в логике своей разберитесь. У вас два предложения, которые противоречат друг другу: "Хочу чтобы юзер который не залогинен на сайте мог просматривать все эпизоды" и "если не зарегился на сайте то ничего смотреть не можешь, зарегился смотришь все"

Comment: Поправил ответ, насколько смог понять вопрос. Теперь так, как надо?

Comment: Да, так, но почему-то он не понимает Episode 1 и не вешает на него img который в if ( is_page( 'Episode 1' ) ) {

Comment: В общем так. Я вам показал, из-за чего у вас не загружается страница - синтаксис. Я дал вам пример кода. С логикой вы уж разберитесь сами, я так до конца и не могу понять, чего же вы хотите добиться. Кроме того, у вас страница может иначе называться, код находиться не в том файле - угадать при такой поставновке вопроса крайне сложно.